# Why has the git ignore file nothing mentioned about excluding files in \obj directory?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, ignore

I'm still feeling out my way around Git so it might be a stupid question. Sorry in advance, if so, but I haven't found a clear answer to it when I googled.

In [this blog](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) it's suggested that one should use the [default ignore file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) for Git. However, I noticed that while the directories like *bin* and *debug* are present in that list, *obj* isn't.

As far I'm aware, those are not files that we want to version control. Those will be automatically recreated when rebuilding. How come the ignore file doesn't mentioned them?

Comment: I see this: `[Oo]bj/`

Comment: It's not a *deafult* `.gitignore`, there is no such thing. It's just `.gitignore` someone wrote for his reasons, it has nothing to do with `git` but is rather opinion-based.

Comment: @jbunting You're right. I got mislead by the fact that the files in *obj* diretory get added to the detected changes. I assumed it wasn't activated somehow...

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Are you saying that I should stay skeptical to things that I find at help.github.com? It seems rather official and well-renowed.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: no, I'm not saying that. You just *misunderstood* the article. It says `GitHub maintains an official list of recommended .gitignore`, note `recommended`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually does mention the `obj` directory, see [this line](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore#L22):

> ```
> [Oo]bj/
> ```

The square brackets ensure that the folder is ignored regardless of whether the first letter is upper or lower case.

And yes, you are correct that any files that are automatically generated as part of the build process should not be committed to the Git repo.

Comment: Right. I see, however, that in the list of detected files, there's a few text files that **are** in *onj* directory. That confused me.

Comment: @KonradViltersten That's when committing from Visual Studio? Please update your question with details about that issue.

Comment: I have VS as a tag. However, the actual submit is done by GitDesktop. An external 3rd party softie.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Okay. It'd probably be worth asking a new question for that issue then.

Comment: I'm accepting your reply as an answer, then. Are you suggesting that it's a case of incorrect diagnostics on my part? That the problem isn't Git-related but GitDesktop-related?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Most likely, but there's still the possibility that it is a Git issue. (So if you ask a new question, do include the [tag:git] tag.)